# How to fast forward a branch when being offline

Tags: git, offline

How do I fast forward a branch, when I `git fetch`ed during I was online and now I'm offline and want to fast forward to the state I fetched earlier.

For example I'm offline and do the following:

```
$ git checkout develop
Switched to branch 'develop'
Your branch is behind 'origin/develop' by 37 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
  (use "git pull" to update your local branch)
```

When trying to use `git pull` I get:

```
$ git pull
ssh: Could not resolve hostname <hostname>: Name or service not known
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

What command do I need to use in this case?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since `git pull` is basically `git fetch` + `git merge` and you already did `fetch` and can't do it again while offline, you just need to do `git merge origin/develop`.

Alternatively you can do `git reset --hard origin/develop` which will work even if there is no fast-forward.

Edit: More options.
Another way is to do `git branch -f develop origin/develop` before switching to it - you can't alter current branch, but you can "update" any branch to any state as long as it is not current. For current branch you have to use `git reset`.

Comment: warning about `git reset --hard origin/develop` : this command will throw away all your modifications. Use it only if you *know* that you want to throw away everything and go to this precise commit.

Comment: `git pull`/`git merge` wouldn't work if there are any local changes as well.

Comment: you can first run `git merge --ff-only origin/master` and see if it works. If it doesn't, you haven't messed anything up, and you can still run a real `git merge`, or `git rebase`, or first inspect the differences between `master` and `origin/master` or ...

Comment: and by the way : your first suggestion to run `git merge origin/master` is perfectly fine. I was just commenting on your mentioning `git reset --hard` without warning that, in the general case, it can lead to lost modifications and sadness (especially if there is no fast forward).

Comment: Yes, I understand. It's just what I usually do - discarding whatever changes I have done and switching to a latest branch. `git status` to see if I really need anything, then `git reset`.

Answer (score 6):

[`git pull`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull) is a shortcut for [`git fetch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch) followed by [`git merge`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge).

Only [`git fetch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch) accesses to the remote repository (and requires a network connection if the remote repository is on a different computer). [`git merge`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge) operates only with the data that already exists on your computer; it doesn't care about your network connection at all.

Since you already did [`git fetch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch) all you need is to run the other half: [`git merge`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge)

Comment: `git merge --ff-only` for the fast forward.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternattive to the above answers:

You could directly checkout the branch where you want to be:

```
git checkout origin/develop
```

Then delete the old local branch:

```
git branch -D develop
```

and recreate it at the new commit like so:

```
git checkout -b develop
```